# Concurrency and enforcing pseudo-unique constraints with views and triggers?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have an application with a requirement that only one business object with a particular combination of 4 values exist in the database. For example:

```
prop_a prop_b prop_c prop_d
a      b      c      x
a      b      c      x <-- OK
a      b      c      x <-- OK
a      b      c      y <-- OK
a      b      c      y <-- FAIL
f      g      h      x
f      g      h      x <-- OK
f      g      h      y <-- OK
f      g      h      y <-- FAIL
```

These properties are normalized over multiple tables and prop_a is a calculated value. Under the current database schema a UNIQUE constraint will not work for this.

A simplified version of the schema is:

```
TBL_A
-----------
a_id PRIMARY KEY
prop_a

TBL_B
-----------
b_id PRIMARY KEY
a_id NULLABLE FOREIGN KEY to TBL_A.a_id
prop_b UNIQUE


TBL_C
-----------
c_id PK
a_id NULLABLE FOREIGN KEY to TBL_A.a_id
b_id NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY to TBL_B.b_id
prop_c
prop_d
```

View VW_MYOBJECT aggregates the data from TBL_A, TBL_B, and TBL_C into the format given in the example_above.

Since MySQL does not support CHECK constraints I created BEFORE INSERT/BEFORE UPDATE triggers on TBL_C that in turn call a function that queries VW_MYOBJECT to see if the INSERT/UPDATE will violate the pseudo-uniqueness requirement and fail the INSERT/UPDATE if so. This works most of the time but there have been instances of duplicated rows being allowed in. Looking at the offending rows shows that they have the same update timestamps (down to the second) so I am guessing that this is a concurrency issue.

What is the best way to ensure that the database always enforces the pseudo-uniqueness requirement? Have the client acquire a write lock on TBL_A, TBL_B, and TBL_C? Add to and/or denormalize the schema such that this requirement can be enforced with a real UNIQUE constraint? Something else?

Below is a transcript of the client sessions that resulted in the violating rows:

```
140228 17:19:19 client_1 Connect  user@server on database                
                client_2 Connect  user@server on database
                client_1 Prepare  select * from `TBL_C`
                client_1 Execute  select * from `TBL_C` 
                client_2 Prepare  select * from `TBL_C` 
                client_1 Query    START TRANSACTION
                client_2 Close stmt       
                client_2 Query    START TRANSACTION
                client_1 Prepare  select * from `TBL_B` where `b_id` = ? limit 1
                client_1 Execute  select * from `TBL_B` where `b_id` = '158' limit 1
                client_2 Prepare  select * from `TBL_B` where `b_id` = ? limit 1
                client_1 Close stmt       
                client_2 Close stmt       
                client_1 Prepare  insert into TBL_A (`a_id`, `prop_a`) values (?)
                client_2 Prepare  insert into TBL_A (`a_id`, `prop_a`) values (?)
                client_1 Execute  insert into TBL_A (`prop_a`) values (1, 'FOO')
                client_2 Execute  insert into TBL_A (`prop_a`) values (2, 'FOO')
                client_1 Close stmt       
                client_2 Close stmt       
                client_1 Prepare  insert into TBL_C (`prop_c`, `a_id`, `b_id`, `prop_d`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
                client_2 Prepare  insert into TBL_C (`prop_c`, `a_id`, `b_id`, `prop_d`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
                client_1 Execute  insert into TBL_C (`prop_c`, `a_id`, `b_id`, `prop_d`) values ('1234', 1, 100, 'x')
                client_1 Close stmt       
                client_1 Query    commit
                ####### THIS INSERT SHOULD HAVE FAILED BUT WAS ALLOWED
                client_2 Execute  insert into TBL_C (`prop_c`, `a_id`, `b_id`, `prop_d`) values ('1234', 2, 100, 'x') 
                client_2 Close stmt       
                client_2 Query    commit
                client_1 Quit     
                client_2 Close stmt       
                client_2 Quit
```